# tesseract OCR Probelam on windows

Tags: windows, c#-3.0, ocr, tessnet2

I’ve a problem with the TesseractOCR.exe. When i click on "Do OCR" the program exit and didn't show me any result.
I try to run in another computer and it works fine.
I test this after hours without results running my code in my .Net Project. My code exits on the line

```
“ocr.Init(null,"eng", true);”
```

I've been reading, and i found that the problem could be with the installation of tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02. I've uninstalled and I’ve erase all the registry but it still not working. 
what should i do? Did i miss some registry file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the tessdata folder where your executable is (i.e., if in Debug then Debug/tessdata).  Inside that folder, you also need to have the proper tesseract2 data (not tesseract3 data).  You typically see inside this tessdata folder the following for English language data:

eng.DangAmbigs
eng.freq-dawg
eng.inttemp
eng.normproto
eng.pffmtable
eng.unicharset
eng.user-words
eng.word-dawg